# How can i execute query mongo in fire/forget mode?

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-mongodb

Im using spring data mongodb. And i need execute query fire/forget mode. Because i dont interested query result. Query has a `$merge` step. And when i execute query, result very big. Therefore i get `outofmemory` exception.

Sample

```
mongoTemplate.aggregate(@aggregate query@, "xyz-collection") // without outputType
```

How can i execute query mongo in fire/forget mode?

thanks for answers.

### UPDATE

Solution -> https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-2645?focusedCommentId=191586&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-191586